# Laravel Spatie Actiivity log Packages. How to add causer_id and causer_type when creating new activities?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using activity log from spatie for logging through models.  the problem is how can I  add causer_id(user_id) when creating new log  for Service Charge Model. currently, the causer_id and causer_type is empty when ever new activity is performed on Service Charge..

[image: This is the db field where new service Charge is created.]

Comment: What package are you using? One that I’ve seen has a trait you place on all models that you want to record. If that’s the case, you would just need to override the method in the trait or create your own to include the user id of the person changing it.

Comment: Yes! it worked. thank

Answer (score 3):

Under the model, you can add the tapActivity()

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Contracts\Activity;

class NewsItem extends Model
{
    use LogsActivity;

    public function tapActivity(Activity $activity, string $eventName)
    {
        $activity->description = "activity.logs.message.{$eventName}";
    }
}
```

link:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v3/advanced-usage/logging-model-events#tap-activity-before-logged-from-event

```
activity()
   ->causedBy($userModel)
   ->performedOn($someContentModel)
   ->log('edited');
   
$lastActivity = Activity::all()->last(); //returns the last logged activity

$lastActivity->causer; //returns the model that was passed to `causedBy`;
```

link: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v3/basic-usage/logging-activity#setting-a-causer

Another way is

```
use Spatie\Activitylog\Contracts\Activity;

activity()
   ->causedBy($userModel)
   ->performedOn($someContentModel)
   ->tap(function(Activity $activity) {
      $activity->my_custom_field = 'my special value';
   })
   ->log('edited');
   
$lastActivity = Activity::all()->last();

$lastActivity->my_custom_field; // returns 'my special value'
```

link:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v3/basic-usage/logging-activity#user-content-tap-activity-before-logged

Answer (score 1):

```
public function tapActivity(Activity $activity, string $eventName)
{
    $activity->causer_id = '$your variable';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you write a bit about how this solves the problem to help guide OP and future visitors? Thanks.